Dynamically Modifying Support Process
I've been asked to change a specific Case Object Record Type's support process based off a field called 'Order Flow'. Depending on what this field is set to, the support process should change. For example, if it's set to 'No Install Required' it will go from
Open -> Processing -> Deposit Received -> Install In-Progress -> Complete -> Closed
To
Open -> Processing -> Deposit Received -> Complete -> Closed
Is there an effective way to accomplish this? Is it possible to do with Apex? Thanks for the help!
